# Where is OneDriveClientExtensions?

Tags: win-universal-app, onedrive

I'm following this article,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632271.aspx

It references OneDriveClientExtensions which I can't find anywhere or any mention of where it might be.  Any ideas?

Nick.

Comment: I've just downloaded a zip of the source from GitHub and can see a file named OneDriveClientExtensions, but there are no classes named OneDriveClientExtensions or namespaces.

Comment: Also the GetClientUsingOnlineIdAuthenticator method isn't even in the source.  Maybe these extensions come from another assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"OneDriveClientExtensions" is a part of OneDriveSDK version 1.x, but latest 2.x does not have it.
And, the article of MSDN magazine is based on OneDriveSDK version 1.x.

To follow the article, you need to pick the SDK 1.x from nuget.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OneDriveSDK/1.2.0

Comment: Oh, so if using 2.x what do you do?

Answer (score 1):

If you use GetClientUsingOnlineIdAuthenticator method, then

replace

> OneDriveClientExtensions.GetClientUsingOnlineIdAuthenticator(Scopes)

with

> var onlineIdProvider = new OnlineIdAuthenticationProvider(Scopes);
>   await
>   onlineIdProvider.RestoreMostRecentFromCacheOrAuthenticateUserAsync();
>   var client = new
>   OneDriveClient("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0",onlineIdProvider);